# I am trying to log into gmail by using Python's 'smtp' function.I keep on getting an error message

Tags: python, email, smtp

I typed in this piece of code:

```
>>>smtpObj.login('MY_EMAIL', 'MY_PASSWORD')
```

Of course, 'MY_EMAIL' AND MY_PASSWORD' are just place holders.
I got this error message:

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    smtpObj.login('MY_EMAIL', 'MY_PASSWORD')
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 729, in login
    raise last_exception
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 720, in login
    initial_response_ok=initial_response_ok)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 641, in auth
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, b'5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbvk\n5.7.14 aJrmwA18KyXqaZIjZHv5Dz4gZja5Y3QikTQDPQ8ax9kmlt3XE2mxq5fsdpcwGDjfmqLzNm\n5.7.14 u1lv3gZWlTeY7FQd2W5C0qxeOBvwnnxo_xr1BCbtN2BpFrPMqbPpv9QPK_rhCWn51iFdA1\n5.7.14 5YzukjqRc9NmRkffFWvrJTkVXM4h2wAzYNZqknkiweAOvYHr8jJz6Z0yWxfxm6VoZLBfxP\n5.7.14 D0jFZdFOXCuSE7L_dCLOo4CXASlsY> Please log in via your web browser and\n5.7.14 then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 ll9sm17758725wjc.29 - gsmtp')
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Have you looked at the link provided in the error message? See [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257?rd=1).

Comment: I have looked at the link- no help.